# Not receiving email notification on PBI Dataflow refresh completion

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I have created a simple Flow to refresh power bi dataflow using custom connector, but i do not get a completion email notification through flow or by manually refreshing the dataflow.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe the concept is that only when it does not succeed you get an email. What makes sense because you would get many emails on daily base of things which go well and you cannot focus on what goes wrong...

Comment: Then why is there "MailOnCompletion" option ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dataflows/refreshdataflow

Comment: You are right, it is there..